# Address of composite literal used as interface

Tags: go, interface

The address of a composite literal is evaluated as the literal itself when used as an interface. Can somebody please point to the part of the [ref spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec) which deals with this ?

```
package main
import "fmt"

type ntfc interface {
    rx() int
}

type cncrt struct {
    x int
}

func (c cncrt) rx() int{
    return c.x
}

func rtrnsNtfca() ntfc {
    return &cncrt{3}
}

func rtrnsNtfc() ntfc {
    return cncrt{3}
}

func rtrnsCncrt() *cncrt {
    return &cncrt{3}
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(rtrnsNtfca().rx())
    fmt.Println(rtrnsNtfc().rx())
    fmt.Println(rtrnsCncrt().rx())
}
```

Also [here](http://play.golang.org/p/y_V5O9YPb4). For future ref., is it acceptable to just link to the playground without including the code here?

Comment: Linking to the Go Playground is _nice to have_, but your question/answer should also contain _the code_ and _its output_. If the code or output is too long, then it may be better to just include the relevant/important parts, and have the complete (preferably runnable) code linked form the Go Playground. But it's always best if your post is readable as is without having to click around, links should be used to obtain more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Spec: Method sets:](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets)

> A type may have a *method set* associated with it. The method set of an [interface type](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) is its interface. The method set of any other type `T` consists of all [methods](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations) declared with receiver type `T`. The method set of the corresponding [pointer type](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types) `*T` is the set of all methods declared with receiver `*T` or `T` (that is, it also contains the method set of `T`).

So the method set of `*cncrt` includes the methods set of `cncrt`. Since `rx()` is an element of `cncrt`'s method set, it will also be in `*cncrt`'s method set. Which means both `cncrt` and `*cncrt` types implement the `ntfc` interface.

If you have a pointer value (`*cncrt`) and you call `rx()` on it, the pointer will automatically be dereferenced which will be the receiver of the `rx()` method.

In your `rtnsNtfca()` and `rtnsNtfc()` functions an interface value of `ntfc` will automatically be created and returned. Interface values in Go are represented as (type;value) pairs (for more details: [The Laws of Reflection #The representation of an interface](http://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection#TOC_3.)). So both `rtnsNtfca()` and `rtnsNtfc()` return an interface value, but the first one holds a dynamic value of type `*cncrt` and the latter one holds a dynamic value of type `cncrt`.

And your 3rd method `rtrnsCncrt()` returns a concrete type (`*cncrt`), there is no interface wrapping involved there.

**Note: "The other way around"**

[Spec: Calls:](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls)

> If `x` is [addressable](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) and `&x`'s method set contains `m`, `x.m()` is shorthand for `(&x).m()`.

This means if you would have declared `rx()` to have a pointer receiver, and you have a variable of type `cncrt` (note: not pointer), you could still call the `rx()` method on it if it is addressable, and the address would be taken automatically and used as the receiver.